# Smart card write error

Tags: c#-4.0, smartcard, windows

i am working in smart card development. i  have created MF (Master file), DF (dedicated File), EF (Elementary file) in smart card. EF file is used to store the data. This EF may be transparent file or record oriented file. i have written the data to transparent file using  00D1000008 540100 5303 010203 this command.i am also try to write the record oriented file using 00DD000008 540100 5303 010203 this command. but i got the error (6700 error code) wrong length. i need the solution to write the smart card EF record oriented file. please  guide me.

Screen shot:

[image]

My code:

i have used winscard.dll

```
     private void button_Transmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
        Status.Text = "";
        byte[] baData = null;
        string sClass = textBox_Class.Text;
        string sIns = textBox_CLA.Text;
        string sP1 = textBox_P1.Text;
        string sP2 = textBox_P2.Text;
        string sP3 = textBox_P3.Text;
        sP3 = sP3.ToUpper();
        int k1 = 70;
        string sData = textBox1.Text;
        byte bP1 = 0;
        byte bP2 = 0;
        byte bP3 = 0;
        byte bClass = byte.Parse(sClass, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        byte bIns = byte.Parse(sIns, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        if (sP1 != "" && sP1 != "@")
            bP1 = byte.Parse(sP1, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        if (sP2 != "" && sP2 != "@")
            bP2 = byte.Parse(sP2, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

        int integer = int.Parse(sP3, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        byte bLe = (byte)k1;

        if (integer != 0 && sData.Length != 0)
        {
            baData = new byte[integer];

            for (int nJ = 0; nJ < sData.Length; nJ += 2)
                baData[nJ / 2] = byte.Parse(sData.Substring(nJ, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            bLe = 0;

        }
        UInt32 m_nProtocol = (uint)PROTOCOL.Undefined;
        uint RecvLength = 0;
        byte[] ApduBuffer = null;
        IntPtr ApduResponse = IntPtr.Zero;
        SCard_IO_Request ioRequest = new SCard_IO_Request();
        ioRequest.m_dwProtocol = m_nProtocol;
        ioRequest.m_cbPciLength = 8;
        if (baData == null)
        {
            ApduBuffer = new byte[4 + ((bLe != 0) ? 1 : 0)];
            if (bLe != 0)
            {
                ApduBuffer[4] = (byte)bLe;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 8)
            {
                ApduBuffer = new byte[5 + baData.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(baData, 0, ApduBuffer, 5, baData.Length);
                ApduBuffer[4] = (byte)(baData.Length);

            }
            //read binary
            else
            {
                ApduBuffer = new byte[5 + baData.Length + 1];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(baData, 0, ApduBuffer, 5, baData.Length);
                ApduBuffer[4] = (byte)(baData.Length);
                ApduBuffer[5 + baData.Length] = 255;
            }
        }
        ApduBuffer[0] = bClass;
        ApduBuffer[1] = bIns;
        ApduBuffer[2] = bP1;
        ApduBuffer[3] = bP2;

        m_nLastError = SCardTransmit(scard.m_hCard, ref ioRequest, ApduBuffer, (uint)ApduBuffer.Length, ref ioRequest, ApduResponse, ref RecvLength);

        textBox2.Text = "";
        byte[] caReadersData = new byte[RecvLength];
        if (m_nLastError == 0)
        {
            ApduResponse = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)RecvLength);

            if (m_nLastError == 0)
            {
                m_nLastError = SCardTransmit(scard.m_hCard, ref ioRequest, ApduBuffer, (uint)ApduBuffer.Length, ref ioRequest, ApduResponse, ref RecvLength);
                if (RecvLength > 2)
                {
                    for (int nI = 0; nI < RecvLength - 2; nI++)
                    {
                        caReadersData[nI] = Marshal.ReadByte(ApduResponse, nI);
                        //kl[nI] = Marshal.ReadByte(ApduResponse, nI);
                        //result = string.Format("{0:X02}", caReadersData[nI]);
                        //Status.Text += string.Format("{0:X02}", caReadersData[nI]) + " ";
                        textBox2.Text += string.Format("{0:X02}", caReadersData[nI]) + " ";
                        //result = Status.Text;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    for (int nI = 0; nI < RecvLength; nI++)
                    {
                        caReadersData[nI] = Marshal.ReadByte(ApduResponse, nI);
                        Status.Text += string.Format("{0:X02}", caReadersData[nI]) + " ";

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ApduResponse);
}
```

Edit:

READ COMMAND is working fine. see the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Two ideas: A newly created record-oriented is empty, you need to use APPEND RECORD first, before you can modify it using UPDATE RECORD. On smart cards there are file types, where the record size is fixed. If this is the case and your data mismatches the record length of the file, 67 00 will also be expected.

Comment: APPEND RECORD command also return the same error code 6700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you use an undefined coding of P2 with the odd instruction UPDATE RECORD command. Also, you have to specify the record number in P1. For the three least significant bits use

- 100-Replace
- 101-Logical AND
- 110-Logical OR
- 111-Logical XOR

If you aim for writing / updating complete records of small length, you might consider using the commands with even instruction. Then you can drop the offset DO (0x54) and only transmit the complete record (value of the discretionary data DO (0x53)).

Comment: P1 and P2 value 00 mention the current EF. i have tried the even instruction command, also return the same error code 6700 and 6A81(P1=01(record number) P2=05(logical AND)).

Comment: Can you provid the APDU of the CREATE FILE command you used to create the record oriented file?

Comment: 00E0000033 6231 83020101 8A0101 A50381010A 8002035A 8618E2000000FFFFDD000000FFFFB2000000FFFFA4000000FFFF 8205064101AD02

Comment: 8205 064101AD02 here "06" mention the cyclic record file, "01AD" mention the file size and "02" mention the number of records in EF file.

Comment: You created a cyclic fixed file with a record size 01AD containing 2 records. Consequentially, you have to provide 01AD bytes when writing / updating a record.

Comment: @MuthulakshmiS, Pls make a habit to select the Answer as a right Answer,If you satisfy with the answer.